# Discrete Mathematic Cycles

Tags: group-theory

(U((Z8),·) and (U(Z14),·) are groups. U (Zn) consists of the invertible
elements in Zn. Determine if one of the groups is cyclical.

I have this definition A group G is said to be cyclix if it contains an element x such that every member of G is a power of x.

I think Z8 is some kind of elements that is modulo??

How shall i continue? 
Should i test every value of negative and positive integers??

Comment: $U(Z_8) = \{1,3,5,7\}$ and $U(Z_14) = \{1,3,5,9,11,13\}$ so there isn't really too many elements to test.

Comment: Why does U(Z8) = {1,3,5,7} becomes that??

Comment: It's well-known that in $Z_n$, the only elements that are invertible are those that are coprime to $n$ (i.e. $x$ is invertible if $\gcd(x,n)=1$). So the only elements in $\{1,\dots,8\}$ that are coprime to $8$ are $\{1,3,5,7\}$.

Comment: How does i test if it is a cycle?

Comment: If i know the coprimes??

Comment: Use the definition you've provided "a group $G$ is cyclic if it contains an element $x$ such that every member of $G$ is a power of $x$". So for each element of $U(Z_8)$, generate successive powers of it. If it generates all the elements, then it's cyclic. If it doesn't (if it loops back to itself before hitting all the elements), then move on to the next element. If none of the elements generate the group, then it's not cyclic.

Comment: How does it jump back to itself for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice $Z_8 = \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8\}$. To find $U(Z_8)$, we need to find the invertible elements of $Z_8$. An element $x$ of $Z_n$ is invertible if and only if $\gcd(x,n) = 1$. Going through each of the elements in $Z_8$ and checking the gcd condition, we find that $U(Z_8) = \{1,3,5,7\}$.

Now we look at each element of $U(Z_8)$ and see if any of them generate the group by taking successive powers (modulo $8$).

**1**

$1^1 = 1$

**3**

$3^1 = 3$

$3^2 = 3\cdot 3 = 9 = 1$

$3^3 = 3^2 \cdot 3 = 1 \cdot 3 = 3$

**5**

$5^1 = 5$

$5^2 = 5\cdot 5 = 25 = 1$

$5^3 = 5^2 \cdot 5 = 1 \cdot 5 = 5$

**7**

$7^1 = 7$

$7^2 = 49 = 1$

$7^3 = 7^2 \cdot 7 = 1 \cdot 7 = 7$

Notice that whenever I was taking successive powers, that I stopped once I 'looped back' to the element I started on because at that point, it's clear that taking more successive powers is not going to generate the rest of the elements since the cycle is already completed. Since none of the four elements in $U(Z_8)$ generated all of $U(Z_8)$, then $U(Z_8)$ is not cyclic.

Now for $Z_{14} = \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14\}$, we can calculate that $U(Z_{14}) = \{1,3,5,9,11,13\}$.

In order to show that $U(Z_{14})$ is cyclic, we just need to find one element that generates the group. We will show that $3$ generates $U(Z_{14})$ by taking successive powers of $3$ modulo $14$.

$3^1 = 3$

$3^2 = 3 \cdot 3 = 9$

$3^3 = 3^2 \cdot 3 = 9 \cdot 3 = 27 = 13$

$3^4 = 3^3 \cdot 3 = 13 \cdot 3 = -1 \cdot 3 = -3 = 11$

$3^5 = 3^4 \cdot 3 = 11 \cdot 3 = -3 \cdot 3 = -9 = 5$

$3^6 = 3^5 \cdot 3 = 5 \cdot 3 = 15 = 1$

$3^7 = 3^6 \cdot 3 = 1 \cdot 3 = 3$

We see that by taking successive powers of $3$, we have generated every element in the $U(Z_{14})$. Thus, $U(Z_{14})$ is cyclic.

Comment: Benguin Thanks!